# JavaScript - iterate over object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an object like this that I get from an external endpoint so cannot change:

```
let obj = {
  0: { "time": 1, "day": 1, },
  1: { "time": 2, "day": 1, },
  2: { "time": 3, "day": 1, },
  3: { "time": 1, "day": 2, },
  4: { "time": 2, "day": 2, },
  5: { "time": 3, "day": 2, }
}
```

I need to get it into a format like:

```
1: {
  1: { "time": 1, "day": 1 },
  2: { "time": 2, "day": 1 },
  3: { "time": 3, "day": 1 },
},
2: {
  1: { "time": 1, "day": 2 },
  2: { "time": 2, "day": 2 },
  3: { "time": 3, "day": 2 },
}
```

Where the first key is the day, and the second is the time.

My attempt doesn't work

```js
let obj = {
  0: { "time": 1, "day": 1, },
  1: { "time": 2, "day": 1, },
  2: { "time": 3, "day": 1, },
  3: { "time": 1, "day": 2, },
  4: { "time": 2, "day": 2, },
  5: { "time": 3, "day": 2, }
}

let test = {}

let defaultRow = {
  1: {},
  2: {}
}

Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
  if (!test[obj[key]["day"]]) {test[obj[key]["day"]] = defaultRow}
  test[obj[key]["day"]][obj[key]["time"]] = obj[key]                                   
})

console.log(test)
```

Both days contain the same data for some reason. How can I achieve this? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: So you want to split your data to display every three items in parent item, is this right ?

Comment: You should look reduce function : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce . It's a bit complicated but you'll find a lot of resources looking other stackoverflow with "reduce keyword"

Comment: @codtex looks like he wants to group times per day

Comment: @mplungjan yes that's correct

Comment: Does it have to be an object with properties 1 2 etc.? To me it looks like you should have arrays instead with indexes - that would make programming the solution easier as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert into an array of object using [Object#values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), and iterate the array using [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to convert to the desired format.

```js
const obj = {"0":{"time":1,"day":1},"1":{"time":2,"day":1},"2":{"time":3,"day":1},"3":{"time":1,"day":2},"4":{"time":2,"day":2},"5":{"time":3,"day":2}};

const result = Object.values(obj).reduce((r, o) => {
  r[o.day] = Object.assign(r[o.day] || {}, { [o.time]: o }); 
  
  return r;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

> Both days contain the same data for some reason

Because you assign the same object reference `defaultRow` to each row. A simple fix is turn `defaultRow` into a function that returns a new object each time

```js
let obj = {
  0: { "time": 1, "day": 1, },
  1: { "time": 2, "day": 1, },
  2: { "time": 3, "day": 1, },
  3: { "time": 1, "day": 2, },
  4: { "time": 2, "day": 2, },
  5: { "time": 3, "day": 2, }
}

let test = {}

let defaultRow = function() {
  return {
    1: {},
    2: {}
  }
}

Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
  if (!test[obj[key]["day"]]) {
    test[obj[key]["day"]] = defaultRow();
  }
  test[obj[key]["day"]][obj[key]["time"]] = obj[key]
})

console.log(test)
```

Simple example of the problem

```
var obj ={a:1},
    foo = obj,
    bar = obj;

foo.a=2;
console.log(bar.a) //returns  2 because is same object as foo
```

Comment: Your explanation as to why the data was the same in each day is very helpful, thanks! But I've accepted another answer as I think the solution is a bit cleaner

Comment: Sure.. i could have done this differently also. Often better to understand why the problem exists rather than write a whole different code for it that masks the original problem

Answer (score 1):

You could take the objects and build a new object with a new structure.

```js
var object = { 0: { time: 1, day: 1 }, 1: { time: 2, day: 1 }, 2: { time: 3, day: 1 }, 3: { time: 1, day: 2 }, 4: { time: 2, day: 2 }, 5: { time: 3, day: 2 } },
    result = Object.values(object).reduce(
        (r, o) => ((r[o.day] = r[o.day] || {})[o.time] = o, r),
        {}
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is start with :

```
const result = Object.values(obj).reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
  if (!accumulator[currentValue.day]) accumulator[currentValue.day] = []
  accumulator[currentValue.day].push(currentValue)
  return accumulator
}, {})
console.log(result)
```

This is not THE solution but a starting kit :)

More infos: 
 - [MDN reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
 - [Stackoverflow search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript%20reduce?mode=all)

Answer (score 0):

Since you want your nested objects to be plain objects not arrays the solution to get last index is rather involved.

```js
let obj = {
  0: { "time": 1, "day": 1, },
  1: { "time": 2, "day": 1, },
  2: { "time": 3, "day": 1, },
  3: { "time": 1, "day": 2, },
  4: { "time": 2, "day": 2, },
  5: { "time": 3, "day": 2, }
}


console.log(
  Object.values(obj).reduce(
    (acc, value) => {
      const holder = acc[value.day] || (acc[value.day] = { })
      const keys = Object.keys(holder).map(key => +key)
      
      holder[keys.length ? (Math.max(...keys) + 1) : 1] = value
      return acc
    },
    {}
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, you need to iterate through your object and make `value` of `day` as your outer and increment the `inner key` as per the number of keys in the Object which you can get by `Object.keys.length`.

Here is the sample code.

```js
let obj = {
  0: {
    "time": 1,
    "day": 1,
  },
  1: {
    "time": 2,
    "day": 1,
  },
  2: {
    "time": 3,
    "day": 1,
  },
  3: {
    "time": 1,
    "day": 2,
  },
  4: {
    "time": 2,
    "day": 2,
  },
  5: {
    "time": 3,
    "day": 2,
  }
}

let newObj = {};

for (let key in obj) {
  if(typeof newObj[obj[key]["day"]] !== "object") {
    newObj[obj[key]["day"]] = {};
  }
  let index = Object.keys(newObj[obj[key]["day"]]).length + 1;
  newObj[obj[key]["day"]][index] = obj[key];
}

console.log(newObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you

```
var result = Object.values(obj).reduce((count, currentValue) => {
    count[currentValue.day] = count[currentValue.day] || {};
    count[currentValue.day][Object.keys(count[currentValue.day]).length + 1] = currentValue;
    return count
}, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// your code goes here
let obj = {
  0: { "time": 1, "day": 1, },
  1: { "time": 2, "day": 1, },
  2: { "time": 3, "day": 1, },
  3: { "time": 1, "day": 2, },
  4: { "time": 2, "day": 2, },
  5: { "time": 3, "day": 2, }
}

obj = Object.values(obj).reduce(function(newObject, val){
    //console.log(val.day, val.time, newObject);
    if(newObject[val['day']] == undefined)
        newObject[val['day']] ={};
    newObject[val['day']][val['time']] = val;
    //console.log(val.day, val.time, newObject);
    return newObject;
},{})

console.log(obj);
   /*
output
{ '1': 
   { '1': { time: 1, day: 1 },
     '2': { time: 2, day: 1 },
     '3': { time: 3, day: 1 } },
  '2': 
   { '1': { time: 1, day: 2 },
     '2': { time: 2, day: 2 },
     '3': { time: 3, day: 2 } } }
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know why you need an object with properties 1...n instead of just using arrays for this purpose. I would solve it like this:

```js
let obj = {
  0: { "time": 1, "day": 1, },
  1: { "time": 2, "day": 1, },
  2: { "time": 3, "day": 1, },
  3: { "time": 1, "day": 2, },
  4: { "time": 2, "day": 2, },
  5: { "time": 3, "day": 2, }
};

function orderByDay(obj){
    const result = {};
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key){
        let day = obj[key].day;
        if(result.hasOwnProperty(day)){
            result[day].push(obj[key]);
        }else{
            result[day] = [obj[key]];
        }
    });
    return result;
}

console.log(orderByDay(obj));
```

Answer (score -1):

My rather readable version

```js
let obj = {
  0: { "time": 1, "day": 1, },
  1: { "time": 2, "day": 1, },
  2: { "time": 3, "day": 1, },
  3: { "time": 1, "day": 2, },
  4: { "time": 2, "day": 2, },
  5: { "time": 3, "day": 2, }
}

let test = {}

for (let o in obj)  {
  const day  = obj[o].day;
  const time = obj[o].time;
  if (test[day]==undefined) { 
    test[day] = {}
  }
   test[day][time] = {day:day,time:time}
}

console.log(test)
```